# what filesystem should i choose for my HDD?

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem

I am new to linux.few months ago i was using linux in parallel with windows.but it makes my machine pretty slow,so recently i formatted my systemdrive and installed only ubuntu in my machine in one 80gig HDD.
now i want to make one storage drive with another internal 500gig HDD(songs/movies/photos).now i am confused..in which filesystem should i format my 500gig HDD???

ext4 or fat or ntfs???

if i want to move back to windows in future for learning .net....which file system will be better for my 500gig internal storage drive.

looking for a solution... :O

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to use Windows in the future, you should choose NTFS.

For more imformations see [Understanding file systems(NTFS, FAT, FAT32,Ext2, Ext3, Ext4 etc.)](http://www.tech-analyser.com/2011/10/understanding-file-systemsntfs-fat.html?m=1#!/2011/10/understanding-file-systemsntfs-fat.html).

Comment: That link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

- **NTFS**, yes, that's the way to go for media storage. It's a more
  widespread and accepted standard.

  Not FAT32 because it has more strict limitations on character length
  of directories and routes.

  Not Ext4 because not many systems "know" how to access that kind of
  file system.

I hope this was usefull. :)